# Why does setDate give strange answer when passed a string value?

Tags: javascript, date

I just came across a bug in my code and cannot figure out why. Two examples below of adding days to dates using Date.setDate(). In the first example I'm passing a numeric duration and getting the correct answer. In the second example I'm passing a string duration and getting an answer > 3 years in the future which is not what I want!

```
today = new Date(); //2021-10-12
duration = 30
new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + duration)); // 2021-11-11
duration2 = '30'
new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + duration2)); // 2025-02-11 why?
```

What is happening in the second example that causes the date to be so far in the future?

Comment: I advise to learn to scope your variables otherwise strange side effects may ensue

Comment: Thank you - the code above was just an example I created very quickly to isolate the issue. In the real code the duration is typed and passed in to a function where the calculation takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a number is added to a string, they will be concatenated together. For example, `1 + '1' === '11'`.

You need to convert the string to a number first, which can be done with the unary plus operator or `parseInt`.

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + +duration2));
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have known about the number + string = concatenation. That explains why I got 1230 days in the future as the answer.